# How to pass Json content type in akka http

Tags: scala, akka-http

I'm trying send a single API request to an URL in JSON but I'm able to send JSON request.

I tried following code in scala

```
val uri = "https://test.com/mock-sms/receive"

          val body = FormData(Map("to" -> "+837648732&", "content" -> "Hello")).toEntity
          val respEntity: Future[ByteString] = for {
            request <- Marshal(body).to[RequestEntity]
            response <- Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(method = HttpMethods.POST, uri = uri, entity = request))
            entity <- Unmarshal(response.entity).to[ByteString]
          } yield entity
```

How can I send above request as JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to read https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/json-support.html

Firstly you'll need a JSON library. The link above suggests spray-json. If you use that, then you can first marshal your Map to json string and then send the request as a string.

```
    val uri = "https://test.com/mock-sms/receive"
    val body = Map("to" -> "+837648732&", "content" -> "Hello").toJson
    val entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, body.toString())
    val request = HttpRequest(method = HttpMethods.POST, uri = uri, entity = entity)
    val futureRes = for {
      resp <- Http().singleRequest(request)
      res <-  Unmarshal(resp.entity).to[String]
    } yield res
    val res = Await.result(future, 10.seconds)
```